# ASP.NET MVC Global.asax Создание куки

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что, когда создаю куки в Global.asax, он не сразу добавляются на страницу.

В Application_AuthenticateRequest выполняется следующий код.

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket newticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(2, name, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1), rememberMe, cookieData);
HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newticket)) { Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath + "; HttpOnly; noScriptAccess", Secure = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL };
if (newticket.IsPersistent) authCookie.Expires = newticket.Expiration;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
```

Я обновляю страницу, во время обновления должен добавится куки. После обновления куки нет. Он как-бы добавился, но ещё не отобразился. Вступает он в силу только после следующего обновления страницы.

Что делать?